# Alternative to using the OnLoad event in an ASP.Net MVC View?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-behind

I'm creating a simple test application so I can see how ASP.Net MVC works for what we deal with on a daily basis. We use 3rd party controls from Developer's Express, and we will continue to use them. If they absolutely do not work in ASP.Net MVC, then we will not use ASP.Net MVC.

With that said, someone has found a way to make it work. He just had to put some code in the code behind. He had to override the OnLoad event and simply just put grid.DataSource = model and grid.DataBind() and it works as expected.

In the ASP.Net MVC RC, code behind files were eliminated. I know I could put them back in... However, since people generally say that code behind files are evil, how else could you accomplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way without creating a codebehind file is to add this anywhere on your .aspx page:

```
<script runat="server">
  private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     //Initialize your control.
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That did it. I don't know why I didn't just think of this in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to do this exactly to make my Active Report correctly generate and bind to my WebViewer control.  re: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668328/

Answer (score 0):

I (seem to remember I) have seen something similar to just doing directly in the View (.aspx):

```
<%
   grid.DataSource = Model;
   grid.DataBind();
%>
```

Work for Telerik controls, and the proposed solution smells alot like this so maybe that will work for you?

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work... I can step through it and see that the model does have the data in it and the grid is set up properly, it's just saying that there is no data to show.

Answer (score 0):

Any controls using `ViewState` will not work in `ASP.NET MVC` - the standard `System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView` is one of them, but I don't know about the `grid` control in the library you're using. Just be aware that any controls that require `ViewState` will not function properly, because of the differences between `MVC` and `WebForms`.

---

Clarification: If the `GridView`'s `Viewstate` and `PostBack` functionality is not used, it will of course function in an `ASP.NET MVC View` as well. However, there is no `OnLoad` event to override, since the page doesn't have the same life cycle, so the solution already suggested is probably the best if this control is to be used.

```
<%
    grid.DataSource = Model;
    grid.DataBind();
%>
```

Also make sure you have this at the top of your page.

Comment: The example that I mentioned in my question was this same grid control. He had it working, but he had to override the OnLoad event in the code behind. I'm trying to find a way to do it without creating a code behind file. I can turn the viewstate and postback functionality off.

Comment: You should just af <form runat="server"></form> and then they *should* work?!

Comment: No - adding a <form runat="server"></form> tag will not make viewstate work in MVC. Mainly, this is because a request to a WebForms app many times is done with a js postback, while the MVC app requests go through the controller, which knows nothing of which view will be rendered on beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a video and downloadable sample project showing how to use the Developer Express controls within an MVC project.](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2009/02/17/video-case-study-devexpress-in-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx) Developer Express's support for MVC is supposedly forthcoming. For the time being, you have to work around issues regarding event handling and dependence on view state. But what I have been hearing recently is that they do intend to support MVC.

Comment: Yes, that's the person I was talking about that got it to work. He had to use code behind files, like I explained.