# ASP.NET MVC Reporting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting

I am looking for reporting solution for ASP.NET MVC.

I need:

- parameters support render to HTML
- export to Excel
- free / reasonably priced

Any suggestion?

Comment: duplicate (or *very* similar): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301986/export-to-excel-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Yes, I can create excel/word files by myself, moreover I've already done it in my application; but I need some reporting engine which compatible with MVC.

Comment: please edit the question and include *all* your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an ongoing discussion about people [using ActiveReports in ASP.NET MVC on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668328/how-to-render-active-reports-webviewer-in-asp-net-mvc). It has excel export support.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Stimulsoft Reports.Web for MVC - the tool exactly for MVC.

Comment: Not an ideal solution since it requires flash.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Reporting supports MVC and starts from $399 for a dev license ($599 with source and free upgrades for an year). They also provide a [working project](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/reporting/general/using-telerik-web-reportviewer-in-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx) on how to use their tool in MVC. I hope this helps...

Comment: This is a bad recommendation.  Telerik may have nice tools but their reporting solution doesn't support MVC.  The project you linked is how to get their viewer to work in MVC (which is trivial)... but central to reporting is pagination and exporting.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one we found to use with MVC was devexpress XtraReports. But it's not free and it's reasonably priced only for big projects.

[Here's an example usage with MVC.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974)

Answer (score -1):

I was going to suggest the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en), you can read about them [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx); however, I do not recall seeing anything regarding exporting to Excel.  To get the data to export to Excel, I would simply let that be part of the request for the page.  You may want to give these a look as the exporting to Excel may not need to occur with in the charting controls themselves.

Comment: Yes, I've planned to use it for charts; but what about tabular reports?

Comment: Those controls do not allow for reporting, which involves repeating sections of data using templates.