# Asp.Net MVC options for business reporting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, reporting

I have a need to add business reporting for an application I am working on. I have found very little in the way of support for MVC natively. I would like to get a feedback on tools that people have used, how they used it (native or hybrid) and if possible links to examples demonstrating integration.

I'd like to get feedback on use of

- Crystal Reports
- SSRS
- Telerik

### MVC Reporting Solutions

---

- SSRS - requires hybrid application with winforms page hosting the report
- Telerik - ???
- Crystal Reports - requires hybrid application with winformats page hosting the report
- FASTREPORT®.NET  - has asp.net support but vendor has not tried and does not support MVC.

Comment: There is a similar question to this one with a few answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722717/asp-net-mvc-reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik says their report viewer in the web forms product does actually work in MVC (they have a statement on their web site that the ASP.NET AJAX framework works in MVC with some special components, and I have used it in an MVC app and with what I've used, it does all work for me).

SSRS does work in MVC if you use web forms and do not use an MVC view; this is still a possibility.  You have to setup the form as ASP.NET does for you, use a form with runat="server", etc.  But I did get this to work.

I don't know about Crystal.

Comment: we got crystal to work at my shop but it was from a win forms page and it was clumsy. Since crystal is just rendering an image I wish it exposed the renderer and allowed you to return the image via a controller action.

Comment: I found this link on how to render SSRS report to PDF using MVC: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx

Comment: Yes you can render directly to a specific format, or host the report viewer control in a web forms page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did a couple years ago to get a SSRS report to run in MVC.
http://dvdtracker.livejournal.com/1810.html

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for late reply, but I've found it when searching for the documentation regarding my project. Currently I use Perpetuum [SharpShooter](http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/SharpShooter-Reports-Web.aspx) and it works in my MVC application well (after I spent some days to make it work as I need). Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: hi, we tried to use sharpshooter, but failed to integrate with our MVC webapi+controller app. We are continuously getting 404 error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403969/base-controller-method?noredirect=1#comment21777881_15403969 Did u find similar problem?