# Is there any reporting component for ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.Net MVC options for business reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593235/asp-net-mvc-options-for-business-reporting)

Hi,

There are lot of reporting components for ASP.Net WebForms (Crystal, Fast, DevExpress, Telerik etc.), but I haven't ever seen some reporting component for ASP.Net MVC. Is there any?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would any of those controls you mention NOT work on MVC?

Answer (score 0):

chart control should work for you;

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-reports-using-chart-control.aspx

Comment: although, it requires your work more.