# Using report service with asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I am a pretty new developer with .net, and now I am wonder how can I print report in asp.net mvc of my project. I want to print report with the data that I queried from my database.

Any sharing idea about it please.

Thanks.

Comment: Google first "reports in asp.net mvc". Plus look at ongoing discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/668328/1437962

Answer (score 2):

First of all Generate rdlc file for report.
ADD New Item -> Select Report
Than , further give database for that report.